# hamiltonian cycle need assistance

Tags: discrete-mathematics, hamiltonian-path

so I'm trying to complete this question for uni and am stuck.

show that  G = (V, E) has no Hamiltonian cycle, where the vertices are V = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g} and the edges are E = {ab, ac, ad, bc, cd, de, dg, df, ef, fg}

i was wondering if there was a simple way to solve this.
thank you :)

Comment: $d$ is a cut-vertex. Any graph with a cut-vertex can't have a Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: And by the way, have you tried anything?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! We like to see questions that show some form of *context*.  This can take the form of showing your work, explaining how you came across the problem, or detailed explanation of what is confusing you.  This helps us help you better.

Comment: i understand that in a hamiltonian cycle visits each vertex just once, and im guessing that it has to start and end at the same vertex since its a cycle? correct me if im wrong. I've simply just drawn it out  and have been testing it that way

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Vertex $d$ is the key. Let $U=\{a,b,c\}$ and $W=\{e,f,g\}$. Every path between a vertex in $U$ and a vertex in $W$ passes through $d$. Use this observation to show that any circuit that visits every vertex must pass through $d$ at least twice. Since a Hamilton cycle is a circuit — it returns to its starting point — you may use any vertex as the starting and ending vertex; to avoid minor complications, pick one that **isn’t** $d$.