# Proving a graph has no Hamiltonian cycle

Tags: graph-theory

Show that $ G = (V, E)$ has no Hamiltonian cycle, where the vertices are $ V = \{ a, b, c, d, e, f, g \} $ and
the edges are $E = \{ ab, ac, ad, bc, cd, de, dg, df, ef, fg \}$.

From my working out, the vertices $ a, b, c, d, e, f$ are odd degrees of 3 and 1. Moreover $g $ being a even vertices of 2.

There were three points that were made in my textbook to show that a graph does not contain a Hamilton circuit:

1. A graph with a vertex of degree one cannot have a Hamilton circuit.
2. Moreover, if a vertex in the graph has degree two, then both edges that are incident with this vertex must be part of any Hamilton circuit.
3. A Hamilton circuit cannot contain a smaller circuit within it.

According to the definition graph G does not have a Hamiltonian cycle because of the **first** definition.

However, I am confused about 2 & 3 definitions and I am not sure if this graph involves them or not.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics! We like to see questions that show some form of *context*.  This can take the form of showing your work, explaining how you came across the problem, or detailed explanation of what is confusing you.  This helps us help you better.

Comment: 1, 2 and 3 are not **definitions**.  The definition of a Hamilton cycle is a simple cycle passing through every vertex. Those are just examples of things that might prevent a graph from having a Hamilton cycle.  Once you've proved that a graph is non-Hamiltonian, there is no need to look for a second and third proof of the same property.

Comment: If you listed the edges correctly then a, c, f have degree 3; b, e, g have degree 2; d has degree 5; and there are no vertices of degree 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hamiltonian cycle need assistance](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958873/hamiltonian-cycle-need-assistance)

Comment: 1. The above property 1,2 are implied in this [QA answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2442781/1059606). 2. property 3 is that if the Hamilton circuit $G$ includes one circuit $W$ inside, then the vertex $G−W\cap W$ (here $G−W$ only removes edges of $W$ ) will be passed at least twice, leading to the contradiction. This is similar to the [EULER CIRCUIT finding method](https://math.unm.edu/~loring/links/discrete_f05/euler.pdf) where we finds many cycles which each cycle *shares one vertex* with another. Please point out errors if any. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: The above property 1,3 can be combined into ["Any graph with a cut-vertex can't have a Hamiltonian cycle"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1958873/hamiltonian-cycle-need-assistance#comment4021120_1958873). 1. The cut-vertex of property 1 is the other endpoint $v$ of the edge incident with the degree-one vertex $w$ ($v$ can't have degree-one, otherwise the graph won't be connected which has one connected component $G'=(V=\{v,w\},E=\{vw\})$) 2. The cut-vertex of property 3 is the intersection vertex $G−W\cap W$ if these 2 cycles $G-W,W$ only has this vertex shared.

Comment: The property 3 can be also thought as the following: If we only keep the Hamilton circuit, then all vertices have degree 2. Then with this smaller circuit in the Hamilton circuit, we start from one vertex in it because we can arbitrarily start at any vertex in the circuit. Then we must pass along it to **use all edges for the circuit when degree 2**, causing some vertices **not passed** after returning to the start vertex and not able to proceed further. (This is similar to 10.5-exercise 34 in Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications 8th by Kenneth Rosen which I did after reading this QA.)

Comment: Or more directly, the property 3 means a smaller circuit will access the start vertex twice, therefore "A Hamilton circuit cannot contain a smaller circuit within it". Hope these comments can help newbies for graph theory like me (at least when I wrote these comments).

Answer (score 6):

As discussed in the comments, the three points are not definitions. They are just handy facts you can use to show that a graph is not Hamiltonian. If the facts don't apply to a given graph, it doesn't imply that it **is** Hamiltonian either - the test is just inconclusive.

Fortunately enough, we can use facts 2 and 3 to prove that the given graph indeed has no Hamiltonian cycle (note that fact 1 doesn't help us - $G$ has no leaf vertices). To do this:

- Draw the graph with a blue pen, and label the degree of each vertex.
- Assume, towards a contradiction, that $G$ has some Hamiltonian cycle $C$.
- Apply fact 2 to each of the vertices of degree two. With a red pen, draw the edges that must be a part of $C$.
- Use fact 3 to get the desired contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

[Illustration of graph G edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0orT.png)

The pic shows the graph G with the according vertices and edges.

Sorry I couldn't seem to add the desired red lines. 
I am making the assumption that the graph is a Hamiltonian ( I know it isn't)
However, I manage to work out that vertices b, e and g have degrees of 2.

However, I don't understand how to use fact 3 to contradict this. 
Also I notice that D is a cut-vertex, can this be added to prove that the graph is not a Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: 1. Use the 4 edges incident with vertices $G,E$ which can form one circuit. So the Hamilton circuit must contain this smaller circuit within it, leading to the contradiction based on fact 3. 2. "D is a cut-vertex" can be used to directly claim that there is no Hamilton circuit in it. This is shown in my above comments.